# How to get geoJSON from spring REST Controller?

Tags: geojson, geotools, openlayers-2, hibernate-spatial, jts-topology-suite

I am developing a GIS application with java(Spring-4.1.5 + Hibernate-4.3.8) and OpenLayers. For this project I use `GeoTools-13RC`, `HibernateSptial-4.3`, `jts-1.13` and `jackson-2.5`.
In this project, I have a layer in client side and in server, I save the features of this layer in a class. I defined the class below:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="MyPoint")
public class MyPoint{
    @id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long Id;

    @Column
    private String name;

    @Type(type = "org.hibernate.spatial.GeometryType")
    @Column(name = "the_geom")
    private Point geometry;

    /*
    *
    Getter and Setter
    *
    */
}
```

In start up of application, I need to init the layer in client side. for this, I need return from server side a json string to client for this layer. I don't want to use `ST_AsGeoJson` or other matches. **I use Spring REST controller for returning my Entity**.

**What do I do**?

Comment: I've used [GeoJSON-POJO](https://github.com/MPriess/GeoJSON-POJO) to solve your exact problem (as I understand it). It isn't very sexy to create new objects just to serialize them as GeoJSON but it works and it gives you flexibility in how you create and filter the objects that are returned.

Comment: Hi. Would you mind explaining inside the post how you solved the OP's problem? Or have you already explained, and perhaps I did not understand?

Comment: I solved this problem with implementing a serializer for jackson.